# Can we generate Microsoft Graph API Event Creation Token Using MSAL library in angular?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, angular10, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am building an application where the user logs in via Microsoft sso using MSAL.But the token that I get from MSAL doesn't work when I try to create an Event in Microsoft calendar.

What i have done:

1. I have added Delegated Calendar.Read and Calendar.ReadWrite Permission for the App.
2. While trying to create an event from the Microsoft Graph explorer it is working.

The error i got when i used the access token from MSAL to create an event

```
 {"error":{"code":"NoPermissionsInAccessToken","message":"The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be
understood.","innerError":{"oAuthEventOperationId":"9fc5a400-c9d7-4880-89ff-0670cfe1b5e7","oAuthEventcV":"fVIhwRVmSAkpeAAnHn03vQ.1.1","errorUrl":"https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidGrant","requestId":"c3bbb134-c902-4f46-b525-f1d30011c5dc","date":"2022-01-13T10:03:01"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure to use an organization account to login with microsoft.